# Diable slots according to differnet service timing

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working in a tattoo artist booking slots process, Artist has different service with different timing, some service has 1 hour,2hour ,3:30 hour, etc and artist have their working hours also like 10:00 am -5:00 pm.
I have generated slots according to service time with their working hours

```
$start_time=$workinghours->opening_time;
            $end_time=$workinghours->closing_time;
            $i=0;
            while(strtotime($start_time) <= strtotime($end_time)){
                $start = $start_time;
                $end = date('h:i A',strtotime('+'.$duration.' minutes',strtotime($start_time)));
                $start_time = date('h:i A',strtotime('+'.$duration.' minutes',strtotime($start_time)));
               
                if(strtotime($start_time) <= strtotime($end_time)){
                    $slots[$i]['start'] = $start;
                    $slots[$i]['end'] = $end;
                    if($date==$todayDate){
                        if(strtotime($start) <= strtotime($currentTime)){
                            $slots[$i]['status'] = 0;   
                        }   
                    }  
                }
                $i++;     
            }
```

Like this but now how can I disable slots according to service time like for date 20-06-2021 artist have a booking of '1:00' pm to 5:00 pm, another user has come he select 1-hour service so 1 hour like 10:00-11:00 but I have to show 1:00 - 5:00 pm slots booked i have to show this booked

Comment: how are you recording occupied time lots? You probably need to lookup against this data.

Comment: I am storing occuiped time slots in database and generating time slots manually by service time

Comment: i would fetch the occupited time slot data and query against the generated slot, similiarly to the today check you already use.

Comment: yes i have applied query for that but which condition should i apply so all the cases of available slots is fullfill